# sql query and while loop that can determine rowspan number

Tags: php, mysql

I wish I knew where to start on actually posting a query and while loop example; however, ***I've never done ANYTHING like this before.***

**I've got a database that is storing all the information for a html
 table.**

During the while loop, I need the query/while loop to be able to calculate the number of times each "width" column has each unique value and sort by the size and thickness so that they all appear together in order.  Then, inside the while loop, I need the rowspan for the  to be automatically set based on the number of times each unique value is in the database.

**database**

```
name    width   thickness    price
item1   2 x 2     .020        $25
item3   1 x 3     .030        $30
item2   2 x 2     .025        $28
item4   2 x 5     .040        $40
```

**html view**

```
name   |  Width    |  Thickness     |  Price
--------------------------------------------------
item1  |           |   .020       |    $25
-------    2 x 2   -------------------------------
item2 |            |   .025       |    $28
--------------------------------------------------
item3 |    1 x 3   |  .030        |    $30
--------------------------------------------------
item4 |    2 x 5   |   .040       |    $40
```

**notice that width 2 x 2 is detected twice in database, so the rowspan width on item1 was set to "2"**

I've recently started using the following code in some of my while loops and maybe this can be incorporated and spark an idea for someone on how to do this.

```
$firstoccurance = array();
if (!in_array($result['column'], $firstoccurance)) {
if (count($firstoccurance > 1)) { echo 'blah blah blah'; }
echo $result['column'];
$firstoccurance[] = $result['column'];
}
```

---

### UPDATE

I get what @ADyson is meaning.  I like the idea of setting up variables and delaying the build of the table until after the while loop once all data is collected; however, I can't grasp how to even build this doing it that way.  Its a great concept; however, I've never done anything like this before so its a little over my head.  Everytime I start trying to build the variables, I run into a roadblock and cant grasp how to get past it.  I would love it if someone could design the basis of this based on the examples listed above in the question.  This is both for learning and for a design I am currently working on so I won't be able to delay this forever.  Its just a bit over my head on how to set this up.

```
<?php
$cp_query = $db1q->query("SELECT sku,size,length,thickness,quantity_per_carton,weight_per_carton,cost,margin,price FROM Corner_Protectors WHERE subcat=$subcat AND visibility='1' ORDER BY size,length,thickness") or die ('Unable to execute query. '. mysqli_error($db1q));
if ($cp_query->num_rows > 0) {

    $sizes = array();


    while ($cp = $cp_query->fetch_assoc()) {


// add sizes into array
if (!in_array($cp['size'], $sizes)) { $sizes[] = $cp['size']; }







    }
}



?>
```

Comment: can you please not use blockquotes for text? this has been discussed on meta, in case  you'd like to see that post.

Comment: I ended up editing that "for you" and it shouldn't have been up to me (or others) to have done that.

Comment: I would start by ordering the query by the "width" column, then the rows come out in the same order as you want to display them. Then you can, within your loops, keep going until the width value changes from the previous value, before deciding whether to create a new cell, or add a rowspan instead

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner - congratulations....thanks for your "help"

Comment: @ADyson - that's where I'm stuck.  Getting the query to order isn't a big deal.  That's easy.  ITs really how to set up the while loop because the table has to continue going because it still needs to fill in each column after the column that needs the rowspan.  And it has to know ahead of time how many rows to include in the rowspan before it can continue populating data

Comment: re Funk's help, quotes are for quoting things, not section headers. Funk is right, although perhaps not overly polite on this occasion. Just silently editing it would be the thing to do.

Comment: Anyway, to solve that you should delay fully building your final HTML string until you know all that you need to know

Comment: @ADyson - I agree.  I was using them to make it easier for people to see and understand.  I get it, just don't respond well to rudeness.  Especially since I hadn't edited it because I was away from the computer.

Comment: @ADyson - How would you recommend setting that up?  The delay.  I've never done that either.

Comment: Create a variable (or multiple variables, as needed) to store the HTML, then use logic to vary what's created, and to join it all together at the end, and echo the final string, instead of echo-ing as you go along.

Comment: based on the example above, would you have time to write that out as an "answer".  That will allow me to accept an answer to the question and see it.  I get variables, I'm just trying to figure out where to start...haha

Comment: Rudeness as the OP stated and not overly polite; have I missed something here? Maybe I should have added a link to a picture of me wearing white gloves. @ADyson Btw, I only came back to see if this question was solved or not. Seems that it has.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I didn't say it was rude. But I thought it was a bit unecessary to make sarky comments along the lines of "I shouldn't have had to do that for you". After all we do get badges for editing posts. I agree the formatting usage was incorrect, but you can just edit it and carry on. The OP can learn how to use the tools better by seeing how it was edited. Anyway, the question appears answered to the OP's satisfaction so we can all move on. Thanks.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner - I however did say that it was rude.  It was the "i shouldn't have had to do that for you" comment that was rude.  Not for the information.  I was away from my computer and didn't have a chance to edit the post before you came back with the rude comment

Comment: @ADyson I admit I was a tad overly "cut and dried" there. I did wait a while till they'd respond and/or do something about my first comment. Unless they took off somewhere, that I don't know. Your comments have been well-taken, thanks.

Comment: @KDJ Thing is here is that you seem to have fallen victim to what all the cool kids do and think that using blockquotes is just that; cool. Oh sure it is in a sense, but that's why I said that to not use them and even asked if you wanted to see that meta post. You could have at least responded to that amidst the other comments; that just got buried. I think this has been a lesson learned on both sides of the fence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by ordering the query by the "width" column, then the rows come out in the same order as you want to display them. Then you can, within your loops, keep going until the width value changes from the previous value, before deciding whether to create a new cell, or add a rowspan instead.

To help with this, you should delay fully building your final HTML string until you know all that you need to know. Instead create a variable (or multiple variables, as needed) to store the HTML, then use logic to vary what's created, and to join it all together at the end, and echo the final string, instead of echo-ing as you go along.

Here is a solution. There may be more efficient / less verbose ways to do this, but it's what I could come up with in a short time. Note that I've replaced your database code with sample dummy data, but the principle is the same.

```
<?php
//dummy data array instead of your database output, expanded a little to help with testing:
$data = array(
  array("name" => "item1", "size" => "2 x 2", "thickness" => ".020", "price" => "$25"),
  array("name" => "item2", "size" => "2 x 2", "thickness" => ".025", "price" => "$28"),
  array("name" => "item6", "size" => "2 x 2", "thickness" => ".080", "price" => "$50"),
  array("name" => "item3", "size" => "1 x 3", "thickness" => ".030", "price" => "$30"),
  array("name" => "item4", "size" => "2 x 5", "thickness" => ".040", "price" => "$40"),
  array("name" => "item5", "size" => "2 x 5", "thickness" => ".050", "price" => "$43")
);

$output = array(); //this is ready to hold the table cells
$prevSizeVal = null; //holds the size value from the previous row
$sizeStartRow = 0; //keep track of the row where a rowspanned size cell started

//this is in place of your while loop, you won't need totalRows because the fetch_assoc function takes care of this for you. This is just for the mockup.
$counter = 0; 
$totalRows = count($data);

while ($counter < $totalRows) {
  $cp = $data[$counter]; //to get an equivalent row variable that the fetch_assoc loop gives you
  $row = array(); //create a new output row

  //get the boring ones out of the way
  $row[0] = "<td>".$cp["name"]."</td>";
  $row[2] = "<td>".$cp["thickness"]."</td>";
  $row[3] = "<td>".$cp["price"]."</td>";

  $sizeCol = "";

  //now for the fun part with the size column
  if ($prevSizeVal != $cp["size"]) {
      $sizeStartRow = $counter;
      $sizeCol = '<td rowspan="1">'.$cp["size"].'</td>';
  }
  else
  {
      //change the rowspan value at the start position, as we know it's increased
      $output[$sizeStartRow][1] = preg_replace('/rowspan="[\d]+"/', 'rowspan="'.($counter-$sizeStartRow +1).'"', $output[$sizeStartRow][1]);
  }

  $row[1] = $sizeCol;

  $output[$counter] = $row; //add the row to the output. We may change the rowspan of the size cell later.
  $prevSizeVal = $cp["size"]; //update the previous size value
  $counter++;
}

//now we've built the output array of cells, we can echo them into a table.
echo "<table>";
echo "<th>Name</th><th>Size</th><th>Thickness</th><th>Price</th>";
//loop the rows
for ($i = 0; $i < count($output); $i++) {
  echo "<tr>";
  //loop the cells within the current row
  for ($j = 0; $j < count($output[$i]); $j++)
  {
    $cell = $output[$i][$j];
    echo $cell; //some variables will be empty (because we didn't create them because we knew there was a row-spanned cell above them, so nothing will be echoed in those cases
  }
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

For a working demo, please visit https://eval.in/961226

To be clear, the above is designed to provide a working demo. To integrate it into the original code, write it as follows (you may need to change some field names to match, it's not clear exactly which ones match to the descriptions in your sample output table):

```
$output = array(); 
$prevSizeVal = null; 
$sizeStartRow = 0; 
$counter = 0;

$cp_query = $db1q->query("SELECT sku,size,length,thickness,quantity_per_carton,weight_per_carton,cost,margin,price FROM Corner_Protectors WHERE subcat=$subcat AND visibility='1' ORDER BY size,length,thickness") or die ('Unable to execute query. '. mysqli_error($db1q)); 

if ($cp_query->num_rows > 0) { 
while ($cp = $cp_query->fetch_assoc()) {

  $row = array(); //create a new output row

  //get the boring ones out of the way
  $row[0] = "<td>".$cp["name"]."</td>";
  $row[2] = "<td>".$cp["thickness"]."</td>";
  $row[3] = "<td>".$cp["price"]."</td>";

  $sizeCol = "";

  //now for the fun part with the size column
  if ($prevSizeVal != $cp["size"]) {
      $sizeStartRow = $counter;
      $sizeCol = '<td rowspan="1">'.$cp["size"].'</td>';
  }
  else
  {
      //change the rowspan value at the start position, as we know it's increased
      $output[$sizeStartRow][1] = preg_replace('/rowspan="\d"/', 'rowspan="'.($counter-$sizeStartRow +1).'"', $output[$sizeStartRow][1]);
  }

  $row[1] = $sizeCol;

  $output[$counter] = $row; //add the row to the output. We may change the rowspan of the size cell later.
  $prevSizeVal = $cp["size"]; //update the previous size value
  $counter++;
}

//now we've built the output array of cells, we can echo them into a table.
echo "<table>";
echo "<th>Name</th><th>Size</th><th>Thickness</th><th>Price</th>";
//loop the rows
for ($i = 0; $i < count($output); $i++) {
  echo "<tr>";
  //loop the cells within the current row
  for ($j = 0; $j < count($output[$i]); $j++)
  {
    $cell = $output[$i][$j];
    echo $cell; //some variables will be empty (because we didn't create them because we knew there was a row-spanned cell above them, so nothing will be echoed in those cases
  }
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
}
```

Comment: I meant write out how to write the code to do this...haha...if you have time.  IF not, I understand.

Comment: I still have no clue how to develop this.  Every time I have an idea I find a reason why it won't work.  If you have time at any point, can you code this out?

Comment: why don't you edit your question with your best attempt and explain what output it currently gives you. it might not be too far from working, and would give me a head start.

Comment: I don't really have anything to show.  When I start setting up the variables, I end up running into a road block.  Maybe its a fail and I'll have to come up with another method; however, I really needed this code to work and its just taking too long for me to come up with a valid option.  I've never done anything like this before, so...oh well

Comment: even so, it's worth showing. Right now I don't even know how you fetch the data from the database and what format it comes out in. No point me starting something based on the wrong type of PHP data structure.

Comment: Updated.  That's all I have left of this portion of the code.  I deleted the part that didn't work and don't have it anymore.

Comment: @KDJ I've added a sample solution, please take a look

Comment: adding a few more database entries and then ill plug it in.  Thank you!!!!

Comment: No problem. I should be clear that this relies on the data being ordered by the "size" column primarily

Comment: How do I format the data array around my while loop getting data from database.  For instance, Start the array before while loop.  How do I add values to the array inside the while loop?  I can't put a while loop inside `array()` function to pull it.  I only know how to add simple 1 value array values using `$data[] = $value`

Comment: As I said in the code comments, you don't need to use the $data array. That's just in place of your database data. You can simply put `$output = array();
$prevSizeVal = null; 
$sizeStartRow = 0;
$counter = 0;$cp_query = $db1q->query("SELECT sku,size,length,thickness,quantity_per_carton,weight_per_carton,cost,margin,price FROM Corner_Protectors WHERE subcat=$subcat AND visibility='1' ORDER BY size,length,thickness") or die ('Unable to execute query. '. mysqli_error($db1q));
if ($cp_query->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($cp = $cp_query->fetch_assoc()) {` as the start of your code

Comment: I don't have access to your database, that's the only reason I made the $data array, so I had something to test with, and a way to make a working demo. Sorry I thought I had made that clear.

Comment: you did I just thought I had to fill it in...didn't see the other part where I had to change the while loop...

Comment: well apart from adding the counter variable you don't need to change _your_ while loop's definition. Again, I had to change mine because it haven't got a database iterator

Comment: For some reason, if the counter gets over 10....it messes up.  IT doesn't include the rows past 10 in the rowspan.  Why?

Comment: see example: https://eval.in/961200  It puts 10 as the rowspan even though there are 11

Comment: It was the regex only looking for 1 digit instead of multiple. See https://eval.in/961225 to fix it. (P.S. There are actually 12 rows in that code!) I have edited the answer too.

Comment: awesome it worked!  I'm about to post a new question regarding this code because its dealing with adding something to it.  IT should be easy.  I'll let you know the link

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165675/discussion-between-kdj-and-adyson).

Comment: That's great that it works. Please don't forget to mark the answer accepted -thanks :-) . Looks like someone else answered your other question, but why have you got two accounts?